# How can I find the IP of my bridge router?

Tags: networking, home-networking, dd-wrt

I'm using my dd-wrt router as a bridge to be able to connect a computer that doesn't have a wifi card to be able to connect wireless to the internet. The way I accomplished that is I connected that computer to the dd-wrt router with a cable and then the router to the gateway wireless router.

My problem here is that I wanted to get into the configuration of the dd-wrt router so I typed 192.168.1.1 in the address bar and I get the configuration page of the internet gateway router not my dd-wrt router, to be able to know the ip address of my dd-wrt router I executed traceroute to see what's the next hop in the traffic and I got 192.168.1.1. I thought the next hop was going to be the dd-WRT router not the internet gateway.

So I'm not sure how can I know the ip address of my dd-wrt router. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard/guaranteed way to do this.

When you convert a router to a bridge it becomes invisible to IP packets (except those to its IP address...), and virtually invisible to Ethernet frames. This means you can't use  traceroute type tools to find it, nor can you see it in an ARP table if you dont know its IP.

The things to do attempt are:

1. Reboot the bridge and then monitor the routers ARP table for a few minutes. If you have set the bridge to use DHCP for itself, or if the bridge reaches out to set the time or do anyIP activity it will appear in the routers ARP table.  A useful tip is that the first 3 octets (ie first 6 numbers) of a Mac address can usually give you a hint as to the device manufacturer associated with the device - so tools like https://maclookup.app/ can be useful.
2. Use a portscanner to try find its IP address - search for 192.168.0.0/16,  10.0.0.0/8 and 172.16.0.0/12 (This will take a long time)
3. Remove your bridge from network and reset it to factory defaults. Reconfigure it, then write the IP on it!